# Import module into a specific scope without using inspect

Tags: python

I have some helper functions that I have shoved off into some support libraries I import as needed.  I have a few functions that have to access globals() for whatever scope the function is called from in order to simplify some logging and string construction.  One such function is format_vars which attempts to use the globals() dict as an immediate argument to a strings format method by default.

```
def format_vars(s, vars=None):
    """Use .format() on a string while providing a dictionary or globals() by default.

       Big Fat Warning: globals() is global to module, not script"""

    if not vars:
        vars = globals()

    return s.format(**vars)
```

This is very useful, to take advantage of it I unfortunately have to create source code from the function and then execute it.  I have the following in the modules code underneath the function definition.

```
FORMAT_VARS_SOURCE = inspect.getsource(format_vars)
```

In the script that wants to use this function I have to include the module and then do the following:

```
exec(supportlib.FORMAT_VARS_SOURCE)
```

My question is if there is a more appropriate method of doing this?

Comment: Although this won't answer your question, the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module will take care of your needs at least wrt scope in log messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you always want the helper to reference the immediate calling scope, you should be able to use `inspect.stack()[-1][0].f_globals` from within the helper to get the globals from the calling scope, I believe.  I know your title says "without inspect", but from the text of the question, it looks like really you mean "without funky code in the importing scope".

Comment: I did indeed want to lessen the funk.

Comment: Need to change that a little bit.  The index of the stack didn't line up correctly with the object that contained the globals.

def format_globals(s):
    return s.format(**inspect.stack()[-1][0].f_globals)

Comment: I edited it.  I was just going off what the docs said the behavior was, to be honest.

Comment: Even though this is a good solution.. I've been unable to replicate the same behavior as format_vars() even if I traverse through each stack frame and check locals and globals for a key.  In try: statements and in other circumstances locals become unavailable.